# ggplot scale_fill_* force labels at top and bottom of guide

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing a log transform of a `scale_fill`, and the top of the scale isn't labeled.  For a linear scale, this wouldn't be an issue since it's equidistant, but for a log scale, the value of the max MUST be shown.

Is there some way to force that behavior given that the value is not known?

[image]

EDIT: reprex

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(tidyverse))

diamonds %>% 
  mutate(price = price^2)
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = depth, fill = price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(trans = "log")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Desired behavior: the top end of the price scale (light blue) has a label for the max value of price.

Comment: Got Data? (sample, I mean)

Comment: You might want to try explicitly specifying the `limits` and  `breaks` in your `scale_fill_*` function

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @42- it's difficult to do reprex for maps because of all the data needed in the shapefile.  Plus this is a very straightforward issue.  EDIT - I take it back, of course I can create a reprex without a map, sorry.

Comment: @divibisan to my knowledge, there is no way to do that dynamically and as I said in the question, I need to be able to do it when the value is not known.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but since you have the data to make the chart, why can't you use `range` to find the min and max values?

Comment: @divibisan I can't use range because the data is piped to ggplot following a series of manipulations earlier in the pipe chain.  The original data object doesn't work, and to my knowledge there isn't a way to reference the data inside ggplot (ie using '.').  I've updated my question to include a mutate() in the pipe chain.

Comment: I stand corrected, @Z.Lin shows how do do it in her answer using a breaks function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `breaks` parameter in `scale_*_continuous` accepts one of the following (emphasis added):

> - `NULL` for no breaks
> - `waiver()` for the default breaks computed by the transformation object
> - A numeric vector of positions
> - **A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output**

You can try this:

```
p <- diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = depth, fill = price)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21)

p + 
  scale_fill_continuous(
    trans = "log",
    breaks = function(x) seq(x[1], x[2], length.out = 5))
```

[image: plot 1]

Or this if you want the values to be evenly spaced after log transformation:

```
p + 
  scale_fill_continuous(
    trans = "log",
    breaks = function(x) exp(seq(log(x[1]), log(x[2]), length.out = 5)))
```

[image: plot 2]

Above are just for illustration. Depending on your use case, you may want to modify the function for different number of breaks, nicer number formatting (e.g. rounding to specific number of decimal places), etc.